# bad performance when passing around boolean-arrays in clojure

Tags: clojure

i've started solving *project euler* problems in clojure as a means of learning the language. when implementing the *sieve of eratosthenes* for problem 10 i initially experienced extremely poor performance that appears to stem from passing around a `boolean-array`. i've found i can work around the problem by either adding type hints or reordering the code so that the helper functions can access the `boolean-array` directly from the parent scope, but i don't understand why it's needed. `(type sieve)` in any of the helper functions returns `[Z`, so it appears clojure already knows it's a `boolean-array`. can anyone please explain why type hints are needed here?

apologies for the wall of code, i don't know what parts can be removed while still illustrating the problem.

```
;;; returns a vector containing all primes smaller than limit
(defn gen-primes-orig [limit]
  (defn next-unmarked [sieve v]
    (loop [i (inc v)]
      (cond
       (>= i limit) nil
       (false? (aget sieve i)) i
       :true (recur (inc i)))))

  (defn mark-powers-of! [sieve v]
    (loop [i (+ v v)]
      (if (>= i limit) sieve
          (do
            (aset-boolean sieve i true)
            (recur (+ i v))))))

  (defn collect-primes [sieve]
    (loop [primes []
           i 0]
      (cond
       (>= i limit) primes
       (false? (aget sieve i)) (recur (conj primes i) (inc i))
       :true (recur primes (inc i)))))

  (let [sieve (boolean-array limit false)]
    ;; 0 and 1 are not primes
    (aset-boolean sieve 0 true)
    (aset-boolean sieve 1 true)

    (loop [v 0]
      (let [v (next-unmarked sieve v)]
        (if (nil? v) (collect-primes sieve)
            (do
              (mark-powers-of! sieve v)
              (recur v)))))))

(defn gen-primes-hint [limit]
  (defn next-unmarked [^booleans sieve v]
    ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
    )
  (defn mark-powers-of! [^booleans sieve v]
    ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
    )
  (defn collect-primes [^booleans sieve]
    ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
    )
  (let [sieve (boolean-array limit false)]
    ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
    ))

(defn gen-primes-letfn [limit]
  (let [sieve (boolean-array limit false)]
    ;; 0 and 1 are not primes
    (aset-boolean sieve 0 true)
    (aset-boolean sieve 1 true)

    (letfn [(next-unmarked [v]
              ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
              )
            (mark-powers-of! [v]
              ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
              )
            (collect-primes []
              ;; same body as in gen-primes-orig
              )]
      (loop [v 0]
        (let [v (next-unmarked v)]
          (if (nil? v) (collect-primes)
              (do
                (mark-powers-of! v)
                (recur v))))))))
```

and here's the running time for each of the three blends. (result has been removed. all blends produce the same, correct result.)

```
user> (time (apply + (gen-primes-orig  2000000)))
"Elapsed time: 108001.047327 msecs"
user> (time (apply + (gen-primes-hint  2000000)))
"Elapsed time: 2599.091978 msecs"
user> (time (apply + (gen-primes-letfn 2000000)))
"Elapsed time: 2768.060355 msecs"
```

Answer (score 0):

`type` function uses `.getClass` method on the passed object to return the class of the object. i.e it uses runtime reflection to figure out the class of an object. Where as type hints acts as a help to clojure compiler to generate efficient code by avoiding the generation  of reflection based code. Basically `type` has nothing to do with type hints that helps clojure compiler emit efficient code.

Comment: ok, thanks. i thought clojure would use type inference to determine the correct type of the calls. and for this specific case, shouldn't it be possible to determine the type at compile time since the functions are 'inner' and thus all call-points are known?